# How to replace old array with new array after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have an existing Array of 3 objects. I'm performing an ajax request to get a new array to replace the old one.

```
console.log('before');
console.log(strucData);

jQuery.ajax({
    url: treeDataUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        objectId: oid,
        structureMenu: menu,
        reinit:"reinit"
    }, success : function (strucDataSon) {
        strucData = JSON.parse(strucDataSon.structureTree);

        console.log('inside success');
        console.log(strucData);
    } 
});
//strucData =  JSON.parse(strucDataSon);

console.log('after success');
console.log(strucData);
```

Logs give the order before->after success->inside success with the respective arrays.

So in the end strucData after success is my old array and the new strucData is lost. Am I missing something or is there a way to replace my old array with the new one?

Comment: jQuery.ajax is asynchronous ... your "after success" log is output before your "inside success" log, because the success hasn't happened yet

Comment: I understand that... In that case how do I replace the array?

Comment: it **IS** being replaced in the success function - isn't the log (inside success) showing that?

Comment: I'm using the array soon after the request, so it uses the old array itself. The log also displays the old array

Comment: jQuery.ajax is asynchronous ... that means you have to wait for it to complete before you can use the data it obtains for you

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the array, but the "after success" log is not really after the request responds.

That is how callbacks work. They are asynchronous! You can specifically make them synchronous, but that's another word for "blocking" which means the rest of your code will wait until it executes.

The ajax request is sent out to a server. When the response arrives, it supplies it to the "success" callback (if successful.) You haven't likely lost your data, but you can't access it until then.

So, you will have use the data then by either handling it in the callback or passing it along to another method.

Think of it this way, you might as well have put the

```
console.log('after success');
console.log(strucData);
```

before defining the ajax request. It will have the same effect.

Another thing to keep in mind is that JavaScript is a *single-threaded* *run-time*, which means that only one instruction can run at any given time. While this might seem like a limiting factor, it's actually quite powerful with respect to it as a methodoly. It means you can have explicit control over the order of operations without running into a *race-condition*.

Answer (score 0):

Since ajax calls are asynchronous the array is not updated this way however if u put this syntax inside a $.when().then() so any code in "then" will be run after ajax call in when() has completed. I hope this workaround helps. Here is the documentation : [when-then](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

The problem was your remaining code continues to run even when the call has not yet replaced your array so code outside the ajax call completes first even as the call is being made. Well asynchronous nature of ajax I mean.

Answer (score 0):

For this workflow, you need to perform a sync ajax

```
                    console.log('before');
                    console.log(strucData);


                    jQuery.ajax({
                          url: treeDataUrl,
                          dataType: "json",
                          async: false,
                          data: {
                              objectId: oid,
                              structureMenu: menu,
                              reinit:"reinit"
                          },
                          success : function (strucDataSon) {
                              strucData = JSON.parse(strucDataSon.structureTree);

                    console.log('inside success');
                    console.log(strucData);



                          } 
                      });

                    //strucData =  JSON.parse(strucDataSon);

                    console.log('after success');
                    console.log(strucData);
```

**UPDATE**

Since sync calls are going to be deprecated as @Jaromanda-X pointed, this is another solution using promises:

```
    console.log('before');
    console.log(strucData);

    doAjax(treeDataUrl, menu)
    .then(function (strucData2) {
          strucData = strucData2;
          console.log('after success');
          console.log(strucData);
    })
    .fail(function (e) {
       //DO SOMETHING IF AJAX FAILS
    });


    doAjax: function (treeDataUrl, menu) {
       var deferredValue = $.Deferred();
       jQuery.ajax({
          url: treeDataUrl,
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
             objectId: oid,
             structureMenu: menu,
             reinit:"reinit"
          },
          success : function (strucDataSon) {
             var strucData2 = JSON.parse(strucDataSon.structureTree);
             console.log('inside success');
             console.log(strucData2);
             deferredValue.resolve(strucData2);
          }
      })
    return deferredValue.promise(); 
    }
```

Comment: synchronous `xmlhttprequest` on the main javascript loop wont be around very much longer

Comment: Since when? Synch request will be necessary in some cases, can you give reasons?

Comment: why was this downvoted? This actually fixes my issue. Is it bad practice?

Comment: @Del - Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest ... other browsers similar story. There's better ways to skin this cat

Comment: I disagree. Synchronous should not be disabled! It has good purposes in specific cases. Just like eval or setTimeout or constructors etc.

Comment: @Del: It is most likely bad practice, yes. Only use it if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log("after success")` is a lie. :) If you need to do something with the data returned from the AJAX call, do it **in** the success callback.

(Of course, you can call other functions from there if that makes the code neater.)